# ErrorException Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::$id

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have create admin in laravel. so now i want to post as a admin to database but when i did i got error like above.
i have a Post Table, I have admin id, I have admin table but it couldn't work.
// To create post

```
$post =  new Post;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->admin_id = Auth()->guard('admin')->id;
    $post->save();
```

I did like this above but i got error.
I also tried as

```
$post->admin_id = Auth()->admin()->id;
```

i got admin() not found.
I did Everything as per instructions but i got error.

```
$post->user_id = Auth()->user()->id;
```

Whereas this works i don't know what to do. i did everything as per instructions in Github but I have a trouble here. Please help me 
Guard declaration:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: show how you registered the guard

Comment: @JeuneGuerrier I have included it now

Comment: @JeuneGuerrier could you find any thing

Comment: Try using `$post->admin_id = Auth::guard('admin')->id()`

Comment: @JeuneGuerrier "Non-static method Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::guard() should not be called statically" i got this error when i did above

Comment: @JeuneGuerrier ok now i removed it error, but now i got as Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found

Comment: You can either import the `Auth` class or Use the helper function `auth()`

Comment: But i was getting errors instead of storing into database

Answer (score 6):

please check your code it should be like this.

auth()->id()

Comment: This saved my day! 
I used `auth()->id;` (wrong) instead of `auth()->id();` (right)

Answer (score 1):

try with it

```
auth()->guard('admin')->id();
```

Answer (score 0):

Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id;